# Proper updating of new memory layer geometry?

Tags: qgis, python, shapefile, layers, memory

Current workflow for a toolbar button:
 -create memory layer
 -save memory layer to shapefile

Then the user uses the built-in QGIS tools to add geometry and finally saves changes via the auto prompt (when done drawing shapes).
When this shapefile is later opened in another QGIS session, no geometry features are present.

I'm inclined to feel the feature addition must occur prior to the memory-to-shapefile save by way of signal slots?
If this is the case, could someone share a simple link or how-to for such?